# Can I make davfs ignore untrusted certificates?

Tags: ssl, davfs2

My server provides WebDAV over HTTPS only, so that other machines can access the DAV. Say the certificate is issued for `www.myserver.com` and the WebDAV is at `https://www.myserver.com/webdav`.

For various reasons, I also want the server itself to mount this directory. Since there's no point using the actual URL and routing over the whole internet, I just take a shortcut:

```
mount https://localhost/webdav
```

But now I get a problem:

```
/sbin/mount.davfs: the server certificate does not match the server name
```

Which makes sense. As explained by the developer of `davfs`, the certificate I got is for `www.myserver.com` but it is presented by `127.0.0.1`, so of course it doesn't match.

I want to auto-mount this volume at boot. Presumably that wouldn't work, since at every boot it would wait for someone to answer Y/N to accepting the certificate. How can I make davfs ignore this problem either for this URL or for this certificate?

Comment: Are you in a situation where having the certificate re-issued is costly? (The certificate can contain Subject Alternate Names, which means it could also be valid for the name `localhost` and the IP `127.0.0.1`.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz It's not costly at all (self-signed) but is it possible to have one certificate that is valid for both `localhost` *and* `www.myserver.com`?

Comment: Just define it in your `fstab` and run mount command through terminal like `mount /mount/mydavmountpoint` and it would interactively ask if you want it to accept the invalid certificate, like `Accept certificate for this session? [y,N]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work around that issue by editing the `/etc/hosts` file. Just change the line where localhost is defined to something like that:

```
127.0.0.1    www.myserver.com all_other_aliases localhost
```

The use `ping` to check it:

```
$ ping www.myserver.com
PING www.myserver.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.myserver.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms
...
```

Now, the name lookup for the certification check during mount should resolve correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple Hostnames and IPs in your certificate, these are called Subject Alternative Names. [CACert recommends to always do this, even for one name](http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName).

Unfortunately, creating them is a bit more tricky and involves changing your `openssl.conf` on the fly. Cribbing together from my notes, generating your new certificate signing request goes along these lines:

```
openssl req -sha256 -key your-private-key.pem -out your-csr.pem \
        -subject "(your subject)" \
        -config <(/bin/cat /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf ./myhosts.cfg) \
        -reqexts hostnames
```

where `myhosts.cfg` has content like this:

```
[ hostnames ]
subjectAltName = \
  DNS:www.myserver.com,\
  DNS:localhost,\
  IP:127.0.0.1
```

The standard openssl config lives in `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf` on RedHat/CentOs, and probably elsewhere on other distros. I've never actually done it for IPs, but [OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#Subject-Alternative-Name) suggest it should be possible.

If you ever want to switch to properly-signed certs, you may find that some CAs may refuse to issue certificates for private-subnet IPs.

Comment: While chaos's solution is more KISS for my use case, I really appreciate learning about this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was as simple as this:

```
echo y | mount -t davfs https://localhost/<URL details> <mount point>
```

Perhaps not pretty, but works as a charm (replace the code in `<...>` with your details). I then added this command to my `/etc/rc.local` (Ubuntu), and it is automatically mounted at every startup. Works without problems so far.